# ConTeXt: Left-justify text to overlap hidden/disabled frame border

Tags: margins, context, rules, framed, context-mkiv

## Background

Looking to left- and right-align text in a footer.

## Problem

The following image shows that the word "Betasec" is not left-aligned with the black horizontal line above it:

[image: Extra Space]

I believe this is because the rule thickness for the `\defineframed` causes the border to be taken into consideration when typesetting, even though the left (and right) borders are hidden. Similarly, the page number is not fully right-aligned (also due to the frame's thickness).

## Code

The following code reproduces the problem:

```
% Define the appearance for the section name in the footer.
\defineframed[FooterSection][
  frame=off,
  topframe=on,
  align=flushleft,
  width=\makeupwidth,
  rulethickness=1.6pt,
  location=bottom,
  foregroundstyle=\tfx\ss,
  height=broad,
  top=\vskip1.5em,
  offset=0pt,
]

% Define the appearance of the page number in the footer.
\defineframed[FooterPage][
  frame=off,
  location=bottom,
  foregroundstyle=\tfx\bold\ss,
]

% Include the section name and page number in the footer.
\setupfootertexts
  [\FooterSection{\getmarking[section]}]
  [\FooterPage{\pagenumber}]

\starttext
  \startfrontmatter
    \startstandardmakeup
      \startalignment[middle]\tfa{Title Page}\stopalignment
    \stopstandardmakeup
  \stopfrontmatter

  \startchapter [title=Beta]
    \startsection[title=Betasec] \stopsection
  \stopchapter
\stoptext
```

## Question

How would you force any text within a `\framed` environment to overlay the border?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
offset=overlay,
```

Instead of:

```
offset=0pt,
```

Adjust the other distances as required. From the manual:

[image: Influence of Offset]